# How to fill in an array with strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm having a problem filling a special array of strings in an automated way.

The strings must be as follows: `"01"`, `"012"`, etc. until you get to `"012...XYZ"`.

I had thought of making a "reference" string like this: `"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` to be able to browse it and create the other strings based on it but I think there are simpler ways and I can't manage to implement this system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need an array?  You can just use `"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` and know that "array element 5" is just the indices [0, 7] of that array.

Comment: Note: Browse the reference string and create the substrings is rather easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just browse the reference string and create the substrings. For that, using `std::string::substr` is rather useful.

Difficult to get an easier solution.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <vector>
#include    <string>

std::vector<std::string> get_subs(const std::string &ref) {
    int n = ref.size();
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        vec.emplace_back (ref.substr(0, i));
    }
    return vec;
}

int main () {
    std::string ref = "01234567";
    std::vector<std::string> res = get_subs (ref);
    for (std::string &s: res) {
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```